# .NET 5 To .NET 6 httpclient breaking change for default SPN port

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, .net-5

I have a piece of code that is used to get a bearer token, in .NET 5 it work fine but not in .NET 6. I know that this is due to a change in the HttpClient (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/networking/6.0/httpclient-port-lookup)

here is my code

```
private async Task<string> GetTokenAsync()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            
            var disco = await client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync(new DiscoveryDocumentRequest
            {
                Address = options.Authority,
                Policy = new DiscoveryPolicy { RequireHttps = options.RequireHttps }
            });

            if (disco.IsError)
            {
                throw new Exception($"An error occured while trying to get discovery document for {options.Authority}: {disco.Error}.", disco.Exception);
            }
            

            var tokenResponse = await client.RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync(new ClientCredentialsTokenRequest
            {
                Address = disco.TokenEndpoint,
                ClientId = options.ClientId,
                ClientSecret = options.ClientSecret,
                Scope = scope,
                
            });

            if (tokenResponse.IsError)
            {
                throw new Exception($"An error occured while trying to get token from {disco.TokenEndpoint}: {tokenResponse.Error}", tokenResponse.Exception);
            }
            return tokenResponse.AccessToken;
        }
```

my question is how can I add the removed default port back

EDIT:
So with the code provided which come use IdentityModel package how can I set the port that is being remove in .NET 6 so that i can continue to use it

Comment: What are you trying to do? The page you link to says that .NET 5 had the breaking change. Which, by the way, went out of support almost a year ago when .NET 6 was released. .NET 6 reverted to the behavior of the other Long Term Support version, .NET Core 3.1.

Comment: In fact, that link says that the change is about **non**-default ports. `non-default ports are no longer included in service principal names (SPN) to look up services. This new .NET 6 behavior is consistent with .NET Core 3.1 and earlier versions.`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yeah, this is Exactly what I just stated, now what I need to do is the following:
1. how can I add those port
2. what are the default port

so that it will work with .net 6

Comment: But the link you provided about breaking change already answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

That's a tricky question.
First of all, this behaviour is just restoring old .net 1-.net core 3.1 behaviour, which [was changed just in .net 5](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/51701)

Short answer, [you can](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/runtime-config/networking#spn-creation-in-httpclient-net-6-and-later) either set `DOTNET_SYSTEM_NET_HTTP_USEPORTINSPN` or `System.Net.Http.UsePortInSpn` and get the 5.0 behavior.
But compatibility might be removed so maybe it's better to align your code with .net 6

Comment: This is what i want to find out how to align my code, does it means i have to call http://toto.com:80 instead of http://toto.com when setting the autority uri?

Comment: If its a standard port you can just omit it - that's the behaviour with .net 6

Comment: The link talks about Kerberos and Negotiate authentication. Your code seems to be doing a simple OAuth2 Client-credentials login. What is the error you get back?

Comment: tokenResponse.IsError is always true if i use .NET 6 version but if i use .NET 5 version it work as expected, research sent me to the default port behavior in the HTTPClient